# If one invents a real life portal gun, can Valve sue them for copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, patents

I am just curious, whether an owner of an artistic depiction of non-yet-existent device has any rights on that device in case it's actually invented later? Can owner use their rights, if any, to issue cease & desist letters to inventors based on the fact that they were first to describe the thing, but not actually invent it?

By artistic depictions I mean pictures, books, games, movies etc. So, in an unlikely case somebody implements a device that visually operates with principles akin to what was depicted in fictional ASHPD device, can Valve actually pretend it's infringing their rights? Or, alternatively, if somebody implements dynamic environments consisting of robotic composable panels, can Valve say that they had described this earlier, so they have the priority?

And, as a side question — if somebody gets a patent on something non-yet-existant (e.g. "portal device") and gives vague description of a device that allows instant travel via connected portals, without giving any accent on how would it work — will this patent (being actually a work of fiction) be actually infringed later on actual invention?

Comment: In this case, is Valve a company that has created this portal gun in art?

Comment: @HDE226868 I assume so, but Valve is just as an example. If it weren't they, it would be somebody else, but question would be the same.

Comment: Don't shoot it at the moon.

Comment: @HDE226868: Yes, Valve is a game development company and the fictional item in question is from the game "Portal": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_%28video_game%29 I guess it might make a difference in copyright law whether the object is from a video game, a movie, or whatever other medium, but this case is a game. If it were also available as a toy (which wouldn't surprise me although I haven't checked) then I suppose Dawn's remark about copyright in 2D depictions of 3D objects would not apply were the inventor of the real gun to copy the appearance of the toy :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Copyright infringement requires copying.

The inventor could very reasonably invent a device without any reference or even knowledge of the artistic depiction in the Portal games. If the inventor hasn't copied anything, they aren't infringing copyright.

Also, with respect to 2d depictions of 3d objects, only architectural drawings are protected in that way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_in_architecture_in_the_United_States

With respect to your patent question, Valve hasn't publicly disclosed *how* to make a Portal gun, so an inventor of a Portal gun would not be blocked from patenting it. You can't get a patent without describing how to actually make the invention.

Comment: ...Wait, for real? I've just been sitting on these portal gun prototypes all this time like a jackass. I think I'll keep my time-traveling police public call box secret though, just in case.

Comment: **sigh.** Guess I'll just have to wait until 70 years after the original writers for Dr. Who have all died. If only there were a way I could speed up this process... HEY, WAIT!

Comment: "You can't get a patent without describing how to actually make the invention." - this didn't stop a huge number of perpetuum mobile and cold-fusion devices being patented although, of course, they don't work as described. This also begs the question: what if someone later does come up with a real and functioning device? Would the "inventor" of the non-working quack device have rights to it?

Comment: @vsz That would at least require the 'inventor' to have accidentally described the same implementation/process, which already is exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: @ParthianShot: I am not a lawyer, but the original Doctor Who presumably was work for hire for the BBC, and copyrighted by the BBC not the authors, so the copyrights will expire 70 years after creation regardless of the life of the author. Assuming of course that corporate copyrights aren't extended again before 2033, which frankly is a pretty big stretch to assume.

Comment: @vsz: if the holder of the first patent were to claim that the real and functioning device infringes their patent, then a court would have to decide among other things whether the patent (a) describes something that (b) is the same as the new device. For a crackpot patent you'd hope this would fall down at (a), since the patent won't describe the thing precisely enough to get to the point of figuring out whether the new device works the same way or not.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks to the vigilant efforts by Disney to continuously lobby for copyright reforms, there is an easy rule of thumb: Public domain is everything that's older than Mickey Mouse.

Comment: @vsz if you patent a device that does X with the method Y, then the patent law protects only *Y*. Others are allowed to make devices that achieve X differently without respecting your patent.  So if someone comes up with a real and functioning device, then it would infringe the patent of the non-working quack device only if the patented method actually works and is appropriate, and it didn't work in the first place for some other reason (e.g. lack of good enough materials, manufacturing accuracy, etc).

Comment: @vsz A patent can't cover "perpetuum mobile devices", it can cover only a particular method or apparatus (that may or may not work in perpetuum). In some cases, only one method is good enough to be practical and then a patent does make a de facto monopoly on a whole set of devices, but if someone can make up a different way to get the same result, then patents allow that.

Comment: user3851, could you also address the case that someone invents a portal gun and then *styles its appearance to be just like the video-game item?* In such a case they have copied at least the appearance. Does that create a copyright issue?

Comment: @Hemsy19: Your question is overly complicated.  Valve's trade dress comes into the picture when someone makes something styled with the appearance of a *Portal* (or *Portal 2*) portal gun, **and whether or not that something actually is a functioning portal gun doesn't matter**